# C#/SQL join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
Table 1: supportstatus

clientid
company
status

Table 2: client
clientid
company
status
state
```

I am also using a table with 2 columns to seperate the grid view results. I am currently trying to make two queries that will return the clients with a disabled status in one table column and their corresponding states in the other. Any assistance with an explanation would be appreciate.

```
protected void queryClientCompanyName()
{
    string MyConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=**;Database=support;User=**; Password=**;Option=3;";
    string queryString = "SELECT company FROM supportstatus WHERE status = 'disabled' Order By company";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn);
    OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    populateGrid(reader, GridView1);
    conn.Close();
    RecordCountLabel.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
}

protected void queryClientCompanyState()
{
    string MyConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=**;Database=support;User=**; Password=**;Option=3;";
    string queryString = "SELECT cl.state FROM clients cl, supportstatus su WHERE cl.clientid = su.clientid  AND su.status='disabled' Order By cl.company";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn);
    OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    populateGrid(reader, GridView2);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please provide desired/sample output.

Comment: For column 1 I want a result to be a list of companies. and in Column 2 I want the state that corresponding company is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need the following query to replace both of yours:

```
SELECT su.Company
   , cl.state
FROM clients cl
INNER JOIN supportstatus su ON cl.clientId = su.clientId
WHERE su.status = 'disabled'
Order By cl.company
```

You want one query that will return both values so you know that they are related.  It is because of this that you want to join the tables together.  I just did a quick google search and [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) has basic join information, so does [techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/1050307) These should help you with the basic concepts of querying a database.

Comment: We'll see when he responds if this was what he meant :)

Comment: That is what I wanted. Could you explain to me how this works exactly?